# How to intercept sinatra http traffic?

Tags: ruby, nginx, sinatra

I was trying to figure out, why I'm getting wrong `Host` header value. The `nginx` setup was like this:

```
server {
    server_name ws1;
    root   /home/yuri/ws1/public;
    access_log   /var/log/nginx/ws1-access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/ws1-error.log;
    location / {
        try_files   $uri   @ruby;
    }
    location @ruby {
        proxy_pass   http://localhost:4567;
        proxy_set_header   Host   $host;
    }
}
```

This is the output of my application:

```
$ ruby app.rb
[2014-02-18 11:30:01] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-02-18 11:30:01] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-linux]
== Sinatra/1.4.4 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2014-02-18 11:30:01] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2486 port=4567
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Feb/2014 11:30:42] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 8 0.1158
localhost - - [18/Feb/2014:11:30:42 EET] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 8
- -> /
```

Before making a request I started `tcpdump` under `root` account: `tcpdump -w 1.pcap port 4567`. <strike>At best it captured 2 packets (sometimes none)</strike> It's supposedly an empty file with no packets captured:

```
00000000 D4 C3 B2 A1 │ 02 00 04 00 │ 00 00 00 00 │ 00 00 00 00 │ FF FF 00 00   ò  ^^^^^^^^^^^^@ ^^@
00000014 01 00 00 00 │                                                        ^^^^@
```

I was able to capture `nginx` traffic this way. Am I doing it wrong?

P.S. I'm running `debian 6`.

Comment: Depending on the system, localhost may not generate any network traffic.  Bind your server to a real ip address like 192.168.0.1 and you should see network traffic.

Comment: @mcfinnigan Surprisingly, I made it bind to `eth0`, but to no effect. I was able to intercept traffic with [socat](http://superuser.com/a/23183/185665) though. Any ideas why `tcpdump` still can't intercept traffic? I'm running `debian 6`.

Comment: @mcfinnigan I thought it has something to do with that I ran it under `VM`, but today I checked on a server with `debian 6`, and it's all the same, `0 packets captured`. Also I misinterpreted results somewhat, I took phrase `x packets received by filter` for statement about how many packets it captured. So it never said it captured packets.